# Is it possible to modify Valgrind to detect uninitialized value errors during ALU operations?

Tags: memory, valgrind, memory-corruption

Currently, Valgrind only uses uninitialized variables error when a conditional jump or move, use of an uninitialized pointer, etc., is done. I want to detect the use of uninitialized value error also when some ALU operation is performed over that value.

```
int add(int a, int b){
return a+b;
}

int main(){
int a = 10;
int b ;
int t = add(a,b);
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to figure out where to change the Valgrind source code. I am looking in mc_translate.c but cannot find the exact change. What and where should I change?

Comment: Is memcheck not detecting errors? Have you tried --expensive-definedness-checks=yes?